# Multi-stage docker build, prevent concurency for specific stage

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build, buildx

In docker multi-stage build, How do I prevent other stages running in parallel to a specific stage?

I have a multistage Dockerfile.
one of the stages builds opencv stack.

```
FROM node:12.22.1 AS client_build
COPY client/package*.json .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM pkg_builder AS open_cv_builder
ARG PYTHON_VERSION
RUN cd ~ && \
    python${PYTHON_VERSION} -m pip install numpy==1.18.2 && \
    cd ~ && \
    wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.4.zip && \
    wget -O opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/3.4.4.zip && \
    unzip opencv.zip && mv opencv-3.4.4 opencv && \
    unzip opencv_contrib.zip && mv opencv_contrib-3.4.4 opencv_contrib && \
    cd opencv && mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
        -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
        -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
        -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
        -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=python${PYTHON_VERSION} \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF .. && \
    make -j8 && make install && sh -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf' && ldconfig

FROM python_runtime as main
...
COPY --from=client build /dist/* /dist
COPY --from=open_cv_builder /usr/local/python/cv2/python-${PYTHON_VERSION}/cv2.cpython-${PYTHON_VERSION_RAW}m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python${PYTHON_VERSION}/dist-packages/cv2.so
COPY --from=open_cv_builder /usr/local/python/cv2/python-${PYTHON_VERSION}/cv2.cpython-${PYTHON_VERSION_RAW}m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python${PYTHON_VERSION}/dist-packages/
```

this stage uses all cores for the build.

If other stages run in parallel, they freeze and usally get timeout on commands (wget, apt, etc.).

I want to prevent other stages from running while this stage runs.

Comment: I don't know how the stages are organized, but is this a situation that is not resolved with COPY --from artifacts?

Comment: @JongWonLee updated the code example to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concurrency limits were recently added to buildkit in [PR #2049](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/2049). With [`docker buildx create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_create/) you can pass a config file that includes the `max-parallelism` option to limit concurrent steps.

Comment: How can I add this flag to the default builder instance that already exists?

Comment: @claudio this is a good reason for scripting infrastructure. I'm not seeing a `docker buildx update` command.